# Reworking function for counting custom post type posts count

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, get-posts

I am trying to rebuild my inline posts counting to a function. What would be the best way to do that? Here is my inline code:

```
$posts = get_posts('post_type=myposttype&customtaxonomy=mytax&posts_per_page=-1');    
$posts_count = count($posts);
echo $posts_count;
```

In my `functions.php` I tried this:

```
function get_my_posts_count($mytaxonomy) {
    $mytaxonomy = get_posts('post_type=myposttype&$customtaxonomy=$mytaxonomy&posts_per_page=-1');
    $mytaxonomy_posts_count = count($mytaxonomy);
    echo $mytaxonomy_posts_count;
}
```

After that in my template files I call the function like this

```
<?php get_my_posts_count('taxonomyname');?>
```

Comment: Im sorry my post is such a messy. I did my best not to look like that, but that `code` wants crazy formatting skills.

Comment: The code formatting is easier than you think ;-) Just add 4 spaces in front of each code line with an extra new line above the whole  code block. You can also use the `{}` button do achieve that.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! Many thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code

- `customtaxonomy=$mytaxonomy` is incorrect. First of all, there is no parameter called `customtaxonomy` in `get_posts`. Secondly, your syntaxing is wrong. If you make use of a varaible, your syntaxing should look like this

  ```
  'post_type=myposttype&customtaxonomy=' . $mytaxonomy . '&posts_per_page=-1'
  ```
- You should make use of a proper [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to get your posts. You should also make use of [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to get all the terms of the selected taxonomy

Here is how your code should look like: (*I have also made the post type a variable*)

```
function my_posts_count($taxonomy, $post_type) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, 'fields=ids' );

    $args = [
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $terms
            ]
        ],
    ];

    $mytaxonomy = get_posts( $args );
    $mytaxonomy_posts_count = count($mytaxonomy);

    echo $mytaxonomy_posts_count;
}
```

*Please note, I have used syntaxing that will not work pre PHP 5.4*

You can then use the code as follow

```
my_posts_count('category', 'post');
```

**EDIT**

Rethinking of @birgire comments

> I feel we should `return` the count since we use the `get_` prefix, even though WordPress breaks it's own rule regarding this semi naming convention

I have removed the `get_` prefix from your function name. In Wordpress, functions which have the `get_` prefix returns its output, while functions without the `get_` prefix `echo` its output

The correct way to use your function when using the `get_` prefix is as follows

```
function get_my_posts_count($taxonomy, $post_type) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, 'fields=ids' );

    $args = [
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $terms
            ]
        ],
    ];

    $mytaxonomy = get_posts( $args );
    $mytaxonomy_posts_count = count($mytaxonomy);

    return $mytaxonomy_posts_count;
}
```

And in your template call it like this

```
echo get_my_posts_count('category', 'post');
```

Comment: Your explanation make more sense! Thanks a lot! That worked fine for me!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Just a small note here: I feel we should return the count since we use the `get_` prefix, even though WordPress breaks it's own rule regarding this semi naming convention ;-)

Comment: @IgreogyVokoramich on recommendation from birgire, I have updated the code. Just two small changes. :-)

Comment: @birgire Thanks once again. That was actually very sharp, and I totally agree with you on that point. Have updated my answer to show both methods

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you have this line:

```
$mytaxonomy = get_posts('post_type=myposttype&$customtaxonomy=$mytaxonomy&posts_per_page=-1');
```

Try changing it to:

```
$mytaxonomy = get_posts('post_type=myposttype&customtaxonomy=$mytaxonomy&posts_per_page=-1');
```

`$customtaxonomy` is a variable. 
`customtaxonomy` is a parameter.

Comment: Actually I misspell it. Tried the other method: adding the arguments to array and works like a charm. I don't understand why this short sorting of arguments does not accept variables?